# JQ RoundAbout plugin doesnt trigger focus event on BtnNext/Prev

Tags: jquery

JQuery Roundabout plugin doesnt seem to trigger focus event when next-prev links are clicked. Only focuses on element that gets focus on page load. Clicking on element focuses and triggers focus event, but next-prev -- no. :(

```
$('#card-descs-carousel').roundabout({
    easing: 'easeOutExpo',
    duration: 400,
    minOpacity: 1.0,
    btnPrev: '#card-descs .previous, #card-selected .previous',
    btnNext: '#card-descs .next, #card-selected .next'
});
$('#card-descs-carousel li').focus(function() {
    $('#card-selected span').html($('img', this).attr('title'));
    $('#card-selected p').fadeIn(400);
    var index = $('#card-descs-carousel li').index(this);
    $('#card-descs-links a:eq(' + index + ')').click();
}).blur(function() {
    $('#card-selected p').fadeOut(200);
});
```

What am i doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: As it turned out, Roundabout doesnt play well with odd numbered elements :S with 6 elements, everything works fine, with 7, it seems to brake, 8 is OK again, focus triggers and life is pretty again :)

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem.  One day it was working and the next day it was broken after upgrading jquery. Documentation states this is compatible with 1.7.2, but I've found anything above jquery 1.4.2 and it breaks.  Use jquery 1.4.2 and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

This should be fixed in v2 per the author:

http://www.fredhq.com/fredlines/things-coming-in-roundabout-v2